# missing sentences while writing on SeriLog asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, serilog

I am trying to make a seriLogger. I wrote this code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContext"].ToString();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Trace(LogEventLevel.Debug, "{Timestamp:u} [{Level}] {SourceContext}:: {CorrelationId} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(LogEventLevel.Debug, "{Timestamp:u} [{Level}] {SourceContext}:: {CorrelationId} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, "LogAdmins")
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestIdEnricher>()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Web4 starting");
            Log.Information("log location: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

it works fine, but the problem is the the result in the next Information line is:

> log location: {0}

I do not understand why the code do not write the baseDirectory instead of {0}

I tried it on other pages with different messages but still reveiving the same result that the {0} has not been replaced by any other sentence.

any Ideas?

Comment: Hi - which sink are you observing the output in? Trace/LiterateConsole/SQL Server/all of them? Cheers!

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post a complete row from the log table for this event? Is it possible you're looking in the `MessageTemplate` column rather than the `Message` column? Thanks!